# Install PredictionIO 0.9.5

Tags: predictionio

I am working with PredictionIO v0.9.6 and node js, but  I had this error :
[ERROR] [HttpServerConnection] Aborting encrypted connection to /127.0.0.1:49886 due to [SSLException:Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?].
After a few search in google, i found that the solution is to work with pio 0.9.5, but i didn't found a way to install 0.9.5. so please can anyone give me the manual of installation of pio 0.9.5.

Comment: have you looked on the google group and the git? [git issue](https://github.com/apache/incubator-predictionio/issues/221), [google group discussion](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/predictionio-user/YUjIOBLxqAI/discussion), [another google group discussion](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/predictionio-user/xHfJiopd1fs/discussion)

Comment: yes i did but without success

Answer (score 0):

OK, I don't know if this will work but following the steps on the manual install with PredictionIO 0.9.5 seem to download the tar.gz file

$ wget http://download.prediction.io/PredictionIO-0.9.5.tar.gz

Comment: Update, just tried this and everything works properly.